# Is this condition always true?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm getting a message saying my condition is always true, it wasn't there until now and i didn't change anything.

Can it be true?

```
    int size = in.readableBytes();

    if (size > 2){
        byte sizeBytes = in.readByte();
        int length = sizeBytes == 1 ? in.readUnsignedByte() : sizeBytes == 2 ? in.readUnsignedShort() : sizeBytes == 3 ? ((in.readUnsignedByte() & 0xFF) << 16) | ((in.readUnsignedByte() & 0xFF) << 8) | (in.readUnsignedByte() & 0xFF) : 0;
        if (length != 0){
            byte packetID = in.readByte();
            if (size == length){

                if (size >= 2){ // Condition is always true warning
                    System.out.println("Size >= 2");
                    out.add(new Packet(in, packetID));
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

I think it's not the same thing as `size > 2`, it can also be true size == 2 (which also has the same warning). Is this a bug or is that condition actually "always true"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`if (size >= 2)` will only be evaluated if the outer condition `if (size > 2)` evaluated to `true`.

This means it will only be evaluated if size is **larger than 2**. But if size is larger than 2, it is guaranteed to also be **larger than or equal to 2**, so the inner condition will always be `true`, and is therefore pointless.

Answer (score 2):

`size>2` is always a subset of `size>=2`. IDE evaluates inner if clause, according to the outer one. Thus, it is normal to have the warning.